# Windows Store App launch

Tags: windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, launching

I'm having issues with my Windows Store App launch. When I use the "close app gesture" (slide the app from top to bottom) and then launch the app again very fast, sometimes a blank black screen appears and when I click on it, it, the Start menu appears, and a "MoAppHang" event is logged.

My App_Launched event code is here:

```
       protected override async void OnLaunched(LaunchActivatedEventArgs args)
    {
        if (args.PreviousExecutionState == ApplicationExecutionState.Terminated )
        {
            // Restore the saved session state only when appropriate
            await SuspensionManager.RestoreAsync();                
        }


        // Do not repeat app initialization when already running, just ensure that
        // the window is active
        if (args.PreviousExecutionState == ApplicationExecutionState.Running)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(args.Arguments))
            {
                Frame f = Window.Current.Content as Frame;
                if (f != null)
                {
                    UseSecondaryTileNavigation(f, args.Arguments);
                }
            }
            Window.Current.Activate();
            return;
        }

        Frame rootFrame;
        if (Window.Current.Content == null)
        {

            // Create a Frame to act as the navigation context and associate it with
            // a SuspensionManager key
            rootFrame = new Frame();
            SuspensionManager.RegisterFrame(rootFrame, "AppFrame");
        }
        else
        {
            rootFrame = (Frame)Window.Current.Content;
        }

        if (!await DatabaseHelper.ExistsDatabase())
        {
            await DatabaseHelper.CreateDatabase();
        }

        if (rootFrame.Content == null)
        {
            // When the navigation stack isn't restored navigate to the first page,
            // configuring the new page by passing required information as a navigation
            // parameter
            if (!rootFrame.Navigate(typeof(ItemsPage), "AllGroups"))
            {
                throw new Exception("Failed to create initial page");
            }
        }

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(args.Arguments))
        {
            UseSecondaryTileNavigation(rootFrame, args.Arguments);
        }

        // Place the frame in the current Window and ensure that it is active
        if (Window.Current.Content == null)
        {
            Window.Current.Content = rootFrame;
        }
        Window.Current.Activate();
```

The UseSecondaryTileNavigation performs navigation when user opens the app using secondary tile (it basically uses the Frame parameter and Navigates it to the correct location using Frame.Navigate).

Where am I going wrong?

Thank you all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you could potentially be doing a bit of time-consuming work in your launch handler. The first suggestion I'd make is to use a custom splash screen technique. That is, in your `OnLaunched` handler try to set the `Window.Current.Content` and activate the window and get out of that method ASAP. You could set `Window.Current.Content` to a page that just shows a loading progress bar - and handle your actual loading logic in there.

The next thing to look at - is what happens when your app is launched while it is still suspending? (Do you have a suspending handler?) Can your app handle the case when it is (re-)launched before a previous suspension / close completes?

I've noticed that it generally seems to take a few seconds before the app is fully closed (even though you close it using the drag down gesture).